# windows phone 8.0 UserControl visibility event

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

I'm trying to implement in my custom UserControl class an event handler to receive visibility changed event, e.g: when the object is not visible receive the event and do something. On WP 8.1 i can use Window.Current.VisibilityChanged but it is not defined in WP 8.0.
I've tried to use DependencyProperty but it didn't work.

does anyone have an idea how to implement it?

Thx!

Comment: I just got a work around that we can set Visibility of its parent and on its parent visibility change we can do required stuff.

Comment: hi,can you please elaborate or give me a code snippet?

Comment: Hi, in the link provided below I already answered this question and provided the snippet for it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating your own custom control for `VisibilityChanged` event?

[Where is the VisibleChanged event for a Windows Phone 8 user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318009/)

Comment: hi, yes i did try but the code of visibility never received the event. just to make sure, i'm talking about WP 8.0